# Linux hard disk mounting into exisiting directory

Tags: server, mount, hard-drive, disk

I am using an Ubuntu based server and I have installed a few services in my home directory. Recently, my disk space became full and I installed a new hard disk to resolve this. Now, I want to mount this hard disk in such a way that the disk space in this hard disk should get added into my home directory so that without moving any files from home directory to new hard disk, I would be able to continue using my home directory with that extra added space.

Comment: Is your `/` or `/home`a `LVM`? Installing a `Ubuntu Server` using default settings causes your Ubuntu be installed on a `LVM` partition.

Comment: Not sure. How to check that?

Comment: run `df` and add the output at the end of your questio.

Answer (score 0):

You can mount any hard disk (e.g `/dev/sdb`) on any directory using following command:

```
mount /dev/sdb /home/test/test_folder
```

But when you mount a hard disk to a directory, the directory does not point to that directory before do mounting.

This means that if you want to extend your home directory for that services, you should copy some files to the new hard disk.